# Showing a series converges absolutely

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, absolute-convergence

The goal is to prove that if $|\frac{c_{n+1}}{c_n}|\leq1+\frac{a}{n}$, where $a<-1$ and $a$ does not depend on $n$, then the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n$ converges absolutely.

My idea: to have the series converge absolutely, then we want to show that there is some $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $|\frac{c_{n+1}}{c_n}|\rightarrow n>N$ uniformly.  I was wanting to play with the idea that $n=1$ would work, but then no such $N$ could exist.  I was thinking about maybe using the Ratio test, but I wasn't able to get it to go anywhere.  Moreover, I am assuming the whole "$a<-1$ and $a$ doesn't depend on $n$" bit is pretty important (why I was thinking about playing with $n=1$, but I'm not quite sure how that fits in.  Any thoughts or help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $c_n$ be a sequence such that

$$\left|\frac{c_{n+1}}{c_n}\right|\le \left(1+\frac an\right)\tag1$$

for some number $a<-1$ and $a$ does not depend on $n$.

Let $k$ be a positive integer $k\ge2 $ such that $-k<a<-1$.  Then, we see from $(1)$ that for $n>k$

$$\begin{align}
|c_{n+1}|&\le \left(1+\frac an\right)|c_n|\\\\
&\le \left(1+\frac an\right)\left(1+\frac a{n-1}\right)|c_{n-1}|\\\\
&\vdots\\\\
&\le \prod_{m=0}^{n-k} \left(1+\frac{1}{n-m}\right)|c_k|\\\\
&=|c_k|\exp\left(\sum_{p=k}^{n}\log\left(1+\frac{a}{p}\right)\right)\\\\
&\le |c_k|\exp\left(\sum_{p=k}^{n}\frac{a}{p}\right)\\\\
&\le |c_k|e^{\left(a \log(n/k)\right)}\\\\
&=|c_k|k^{|a|}\frac1{n^{|a|}}
\end{align}$$

Inasmuch as the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{n^{|a|}}$ converges for $|a|>1$, the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |c_n|$ converges and hence the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n$ converges  absolutely.

Comment: This is a neat way of doing it!  My big O notation is a little fuzzy, but I like it :)

Comment: Pleased to hear.  [Here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) is an article on the Big O notation that should help.

Comment: I suppose I am a little thrown off at you using $a>1$ in the second to last line.  $a<-1$ in the statement of the problem.  I may be (probably am) missing something though.

Comment: Good catch.  That was a typographical error.  It should have been $|a|>1$.  I've edited accordingly.

Comment: Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

One method is to use Raabe's Test, a refinement of the Ratio Test. Let $S=\sum_n c_n$ be a series of positive terms. If it exists, let
$$
\rho =\lim_{n\to\infty} n\left(\frac{c_n}{c_{n+1}}-1\right)
$$Then
$$
\begin{cases}
\rho >0 & S \text{ converges}\\
\rho <0 & S \text{ diverges}\\
\rho =0 & \text{ (inconclusive)}\\
\end{cases}
$$Since we know something about the ratios, we have
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} n\left(\frac{c_n}{c_{n+1}}-1\right) \geq \lim_{n\to\infty} n\left((1+a/n)^{-1}-1\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}-\frac{a n}{a+n} = -a>1
$$
So your series converges.

- https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RaabesTest.html

Comment: What if $S$ isn't a series of positive terms?

Comment: We can apply it to $\sum_n |c_n|$

Comment: Thank you very much!  I never thought about using Raabe's test here.  I like this.