# If $|\frac{c_{n+1}}{c_n}|\leq1+\frac{a}{n}$, where $a<-1$, $a$ does not depend on $n$, then the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n$ converges absolutely

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, solution-verification, uniform-convergence, absolute-convergence

Question: If $|\frac{c_{n+1}}{c_n}|\leq1+\frac{a}{n}$, where $a<-1$ and $a$ does not depend on $n$, then the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n$ converges absolutely.

My attempt: Let $\epsilon>0$.  To show $\sum c_n$ converges absolutely, we want to show that there exists an $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $|\frac{c_{n+1}}{c_n}|$ converges uniformly to some constant $n>N$.  Since $a<-1$, there is some $N_0$ such that $||\frac{c_{n+1}}{c_n}|-1|<\epsilon$ whenever $n>N_0$.  Thus, $|\frac{c_{n+1}}{c_n}|$ converges uniformly (to $1^-$) hence $\sum c_n$ converges absolutely.

I actually asked this question a little over a year ago here: [Showing a series converges absolutely](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3737846/showing-a-series-converges-absolutely) and got a couple neat answers, but I was wondering if this would be a more "direct" (I don't know if that is the right word) of doing it.   Or, is there something I messed up?  Any help is, as always, greatly appreciated!  Thank you.

Comment: I think your method is fine, however, I would be a bit more careful with the "uniform convergence" as it is more often used for functions (there is nothing wrong with what you have written, however, I think saying $|c_{n+1}/c_{n}|$ is bounded by $1 - \delta$ for some small $\delta$ would have also been sufficient).

Comment: Your proof is not valid. To apply ratio  test what you need is $\lim \frac {|c_{n+1}|} {|c_n|} <1$ and you did not prove this.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Is there a way to salvage this method?  Could you help me out if you have time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is known as Raabe's test. The criteria is as follows:

1. If there is $a>1$ such that $\frac{|a_{n+1}|}{|a_n|}\leq 1-\frac{a}{n}$  for all $n\geq n_0$, then $\sum_na_n$ converges absolutely
2. If there is $a\leq 1$ such that $\frac{|a_{n+1}|}{|a_n|}\geq 1-\frac{a}{n}$  for all $n\geq n_0$, then $\sum_n|a_n|$ diverges.

Another version of the Raabe's test is [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test#2._Raabe%27s_test)

Here is one way to prove this.

> Proposition: Suppose $a_n, b_n>0$, and that there is $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\leq \frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}$ for all $n\geq n_0$.
>
> 1. If $\sum_nb_n$ converges, so does $\sum_na_n$.
> 2. If $\sum_na_n$ diverges, so does $\sum_nb_n$.

*Proof:* The hypothesis may be rewritten as $\frac{a_{n+1}}{b_{n+1}}\leq \frac{a_n}{b_n}$ for all $n\geq n_0$. Thus, the sequence of ratios $\frac{a_n}{b_n}$ is monotone non increasing for $n\geq n_0$ and so it bounded above. Hence, there is $c>0$ such that $a_n\leq c b_n$ for all $n\geq n_0$. The conclusions (1) and (2) follow immediately.

> Lemma: If $a>1$ or $a<0$, then $1-ax\leq (1-x)^a$ for all $0\leq x\leq 1$. If $0\leq a\leq1$, then $(1-x)^a\leq 1-ax$ for all $0\leq x\leq 1$.

*Proof:*
Define $g(x)=ax + (1-x)^a$. Then, $g'(x)=a\big(1-(1-x)^{a-1}\big)$. If $a>1$,  $g$ is monotone nondecreasing on $[0,1]$ and so $g(x)\geq g(0)=1$ for all $0\leq x\leq 1$. If $0\leq a<1$, then $g$ is monotone non increasing on $[0,1]$ and $g(x)\leq g(0)=1$ for all $0\leq x\leq 1$.  Finally, if $a<0$, then $g$ is monotone nonincreasing on $[0,1]$ and $g(x)\leq g(0)=1$ for all $0\leq x\leq 1$.

**Proof of Raabe's:**
If $a>1$ and $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\leq 1-\frac{a}{n}$ for all $n\geq n_0$, then
$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\leq 1-\frac{a}{n}\leq\Big(1-\frac1n\Big)^a=\frac{(n-1)^a}{n^a},\qquad n\geq n_0$$
Apply the Proposition above with $b_n=\frac{1}{(n-1)^a}$.

If $a\leq0$ and  $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\geq 1-\frac{a}{n}$ for all $n\geq n_0$, then $a_{n+1}\geq a_{n}$ for all $n\geq n_0$ and so, $a_n\not\rightarrow0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$

If $0< a\leq1$ and $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\geq 1-\frac{a}{n}$ for all $n\geq n_0$, then
$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\geq 1-\frac{a}{n}\geq\Big(1-\frac1n\Big)^a=\frac{(n-1)^a}{n^a},\qquad n\geq n_0$$
Since $\sum_n\frac{1}{(n-1)^a}$ diverges, so does $\sum_na_n$ by the Proposition above.

---

Reference: Courant, R. and Fritz, J. *Introduction to Calculus and Analysis, Vol. 1*, pp. 567 (Classics in Mathematics) 1999th Edition.

---

**Edit:** the method presented in his solution is more about insight than ingenuity, for it is based on the fact that  many ratio type tests of convergence  can be reduced to the setting the proposition above. This was observed by some clever people in the late 1800's, and came up with the systematic treatment I presented above.

The answer provided by Jack D'Aurizio for example  is more ingenious once one makes the connection to the harmonic series: $\frac1n\leq H_n=\sum^n_{k=1}\frac1k\sim\log n$.

Here is another more pedestrian solution building things from the ground up. For simplicity assume $a_n>0$ for all $n$.

If  $a>1$, and  $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\leq 1-\frac{a}{n}$ for all $n\geq1$, then
$$na_{n+1}\leq na_n-aa_n=(n-1)a_n-(a-1)a_n$$
and so,
$$(n-1)a_n-na_{n+1}\geq (a-1)a_n>0$$
This means that the sequence $(n-1)a_n$ is monotone non increasing, and adding terms telescopically gives
$$a_2\geq a_2-na_{n+1}\geq (a-1)(a_1+\ldots a_n)$$
This shows that the sequence $\sum^n_{k=1}a_n$ is bounded and so, the series converges.

If $a\leq 1$ and $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\geq 1-\frac{a}{n}$ for all $n\geq n_0$ then
$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\geq\frac{n-a}{n}\geq \frac{n-1}{n}$$
Since $\sum_n\frac{1}{n-1}$ diverges, so does $\sum_na_n$.

Comment: But our problem has $a<-1$, but in Raabe's test, $a>1$

Comment: Notice that you have $1+\frac{a}{n}$ with $a<-1$. I just switch things to a more convenient form $1-\frac{a}{n}$ with $a>1$

Comment: Reading through this again, it appears quite simple once the proposition and lemma are in place! +1

Comment: @User7238: there are other, more direct if you will, ways to prove this result. The way I chose to present here is more systematic for it gives a general method to approach other ratio type convergence tests. I am choosing hindsight over of ingenuity. I will add shortly a more pedestrian way (portably more ingenious) to work this out.

Comment: I would appreciate that very much!  I am looking forward to it!

Comment: @User7238: done!

Comment: I can't tell you how much I appreciate your time and effort!  That helps SO MUCH!  I have been working on, and trying to understand methods for this problem for quite some time now, so it really does mean a lot to me.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If
$$ \left|\frac{c_{n+1}}{c_n}\right| \leq 1-\frac{k}{n}\qquad\text{with }k>1 $$
then
$$|c_{n+1}|\leq |c_n| e^{-k/n}\leq |c_1|\exp\left(-k H_n\right)\leq |c_1|\exp(-k\log n)=\frac{|c_1|}{n^k}$$
and $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^k} = \zeta(k)< +\infty$ for any $k>1$.

Comment: Thank you, but what is $H_n$?

Answer (score 2):

Let $|a|<n_0\in\Bbb N.$ For $n>n_0$ we have $$|\;\ln |c_{n+1}|\;|=|\;\ln |c_{n_0}\prod_{j=n_0}^n|c_{j+1}/c_j|\;|\ge$$ $$\ge  |\;\ln |c_{n_0}\prod_{j=n_0}^n(1+a/j)|\;|\ge$$ $$\ge  -|\;\ln |c_{n_0}|\;|+\sum_{j=n_0}^n|a|/j \quad (\bullet)$$ because if $-1<a/j<0$ then $\ln (1+a/j)=(a/j)-(a/j)^2/2+(a/j)^3/3-...<(a/j).$

Now $(-\ln n)+\sum_{j=1}^n(1/j)$ converges to the Euler-Macheroni constant $\gamma\approx 0.577$ (a. k.a. Euler's constant) as $n\to\infty$. So $\lim_{n\to\infty}[-\ln n+\sum_{j=n_0}^n(1/j)\,]=K$ exists in $\Bbb R.$

So by $(\bullet)$, for all but finitely many $n>n_0$ we have $|\ln |c_{n+1}|\;|>-|\ln |c_{n_0}|\;|+|a|\ln n+|a|K-1.$ For convenience let $L=-|\ln |c_{n_0}|\;|+|a|K-1.$ So for all but finitely many $n$ we have $$(\bullet\bullet)\quad |\ln |c_{n+1}|\;|>L+|a|\ln n.$$ So $(|c_n|)_{n>n_0}$ is a decreasing positive sequence whose log's tend to $\infty,$ so by $(\bullet\bullet)$ we have $$|c_{n+1}|<\frac {e^{-L}}{n^{|a|}}$$ for all but finitely many $n.$

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that there exists an $n_0\in\Bbb N$ such that $1+\frac a{n_0}>0$ and we have $|\frac{c_{n+1}}{c_n}|\leq 1+\frac an$ for all $n\geq n_0$. Then by iteration we have $|c_{n+1}|\leq|c_{n_0}|P$ where $P=\prod_{k=n_0}^n(1+\frac ak).$ Now,
$$\ln P=\sum_{k=n_0}^n\ln(1+\frac ak)<\int_{n_0}^n\ln(1+\frac ax)dx<(n+a)\ln(n+a)-n\ln n+c$$
where $c$ is a constant. So, $P<k\frac{(n+a)^{n+a}}{n^n}$ where $k$ is a positive constant. Therefore $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}c_n$ is absolutely convergent if $\sum_{n=n_0}^\infty\frac{(n+a)^{n+a}}{n^n}$ is converent. But this last series is less than $\sum_{n=n_0}^\infty\frac{n^{n+a}}{n^n}=\sum_{n=n_0}^\infty n^a$ which is convergent since $a<-1$.